# How to create Caffeine cache that has no max value and does not expire?

Tags: java, spring, caching, caffeine

I have implemented a `Caffeine` cache as follows:

```
private static Cache<String, MyObject> MyObjectCache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .build();
```

How can I ensure that the cache has no max size and does not expire?

Comment: You've just done it in that code sample, haven't you? You've provided no maximum size and no expiry time after read or write, so I can't see why it would enforce a maximum size or expire.

Comment: @MichaelBerry is correct. Unlike some other caching libraries, Caffeine does not have implicit default bounds. The obvious code, yours, works exactly how you would expect it to.

Comment: OK I was not aware the defaults did not have bonds. feel free to answer so I can accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Caffeine cache can be implemented with no max value and no expiration by the following:

```
private static Cache<String, MyObject> MyObjectCache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .build();
```

I.e. it is created without a max value and expiration as default.