# How to set a Caffeine cache to not expire

Tags: java, spring-boot, caffeine

I have a simple spring boot app and I'm using Caffeine for caching. I'm configuring it using spring boot properties. How do I sent it to not expire?

Comment: Don’t set any expiration settings?

Answer (score 1):

How about you just set it to sufficiently high value just like they are doing here.
https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/e8ff6d3261e7f5666d2b486352cc04b2874d70ed/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Async.java

You can implement your own expiry like this.

```
Caffeine
            .newBuilder()
            .expireAfter(new Expiry<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public long expireAfterCreate(@Nonnull String key, @Nonnull String value,
                                              long currentTime) {
                    //return Duration.ofDays(1).toNanos();
                    return   Long.MAX_VALUE;
                }

                @Override
                public long expireAfterUpdate(@Nonnull String key, @Nonnull String value, long currentTime,
                                              long currentDuration) {
                    return currentDuration;
                }

                @Override
                public long expireAfterRead(@Nonnull String key, @Nonnull String value, long currentTime,
                                            long currentDuration) {
                    return currentDuration;
                }
            }).build()
```

Comment: Yeah, could do it that way. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I thought this is enough: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59898158/10582056. Should I write custom code to make cache not expire?